# displaying data from web in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, asihttprequest

i am new to iOS Development so please go easy on me.

I have an existing ecommerce site set up using oscommerce that requires a user to log in to view products, i want to build an app that will access this store.

That being said i have been able to successfully connect to the store using the ASIHTTPRequest Library.  The only thing i am unsure of is how to get the information back so that i can build my application. i have heard people saying XML, and JSON but i guess i am still not sure how i can get the data on my site into my app. like getting categories into a uitableview for example.

Does anyone have any examples or links to where i might start.

Comment: What is your eCommerce site built with? Is custom written or are you using a commercial / FOSS project?

Comment: you need to implement web-services for this purpose. Web-services are server side codes which can manipulate your online store's DB and can return desired data and then you get this raw data and display this as per your requirement. Web-services can use any format JSON or XML. JSON is light weight so mostly I'd used this in my projects. You can use any of them depends on your needs/expertise. You might need to get someone who can help you out with the server side code.

Comment: thank you for the replys, Devraj: i am using oscommerce, Ahmed: i have used json before so i will look into it a little more, i appreciate the help

Comment: http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/7459

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function you will get the response of server i:e the ResponseData returned by server,
 all you need is to parse this data and save it locally for further use.
 For parsing you can there are options to use NSXMLParser, TouchXMLParser, JSON 
 parsing. Its on you what to use.

```
- (NSData*)sendRequest
{
   ASIHTTPRequest *getRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com"]];
 NSData *responseData = nil;
    [getRequest start];


    //if we have encounter any error
    NSError *error = [getRequest error];

    if (!error) 
    {
        responseData = [getRequest responseData];

    }

     return responseData;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info, this was what i eventually ended up using. I am able to get started with a list of categories from my store but i am unsure how to call specific php functions like adding a product to cart. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I work on a hosted tool called Kumulos that allows you to connect iOS applications to remote data sources (such as your oscommerce installation) by creating an intermediate web service.

With Kumulos you build API methods to access your data from the iPhone. Your API-related Obj-C is built for you, and when you call the API, your iOS app will receive native Obj-C data types, avoiding the need to parse any JSON or XML. This makes integration quick and painless.

It's currently in beta testing and free to use. We'd love to hear your feedback if you're interested in giving it a try.

We have a video tutorial on [how to hook up an app to wordpress](http://docs.kumulos.com/videos/hookup-kumulos-to-wordpress/), and the idea should be the same for oscommerce. You can see more information and register at: www.kumulos.com

*Disclaimer: I am one of the developers involved in Kumulos*

Comment: i took a look at your app and i tried it out. it is easy to use and not too hard to set up, but really wasn't what i was looking for since i already have a full database with all of my products this would almost be "reinventing the wheel", but i appreciate the response and will look into Kumulos for future projects.

Comment: @dM5 You're welcome, thanks for taking a look and giving feedback!